# Provide user name when using vim with scp

Tags: ssh, vim, scp

I was reading about SSH here http://blogs.perl.org/users/smylers/2011/08/ssh-productivity-tips.html and found that you can use `vim` to directly modify a file on a remote server that you can `ssh` into. Like:

```
vim scp://testserver/path/filename
```

And it works perfectly except that I need to provide a **username** (because I have a different user name on the server). How can I do that? (vim asks for the password, but uses my local username)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open file using path relative to username's home directory run,

```
vim scp://username@remotehost/file
which is same as,
vim scp://username@remotehost//home/username/file
```

If you want to enter the absolute path to a file starting from / instead of your home directory, use two slashes after the host name run,

```
vim scp://username@remotehost//absolute/path/to/file
```

Editing your file is done exactly the same as for local files, including using :w to save your changes.

Behind the scene vim uses `netrw` plugin to read files, write files, browse over a network using various protocols like scp, rsync, ftp etc.
`:help netrw` inside vim can give you a lot more information.

Answer (score 3):

Trying a couple things, I got this message:

```
format: protocol://[user@]hostname[:port]/[path]
```

Note that `[path]` will be interpreted from your home directory unless you add an additional `/` (`vim scp://user@host//etc/vim/vimrc`).